# ListView with custom ArrayAdapter: Works fine, until I need to change the number of items?

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview

I have a custom ArrayAdapter I use to manage my ListView:

```
public class FilesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PutioFileLayout> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    PutioFileLayout data[] = null;

    public FilesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, PutioFileLayout[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        FileHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new FileHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_fileName);
            holder.textDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_fileDesc);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_fileIcon);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (FileHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        PutioFileLayout file = data[position];
        holder.textName.setText(file.name);
        holder.textDescription.setText(file.description);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(file.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class FileHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textDescription;
        ImageView imgIcon;
    }
}
```

And in my Fragment, I declare these before the `onCreate`:

```
private PutioFileLayout[] fileData;
private FilesAdapter adapter;
```

Then, in the `onCreate`, I initialize it with this, as a placeholder for the user:

```
    fileData = new PutioFileLayout[] {
            new PutioFileLayout("Loading...", "Your files will appear shortly.", R.drawable.ic_launcher, false)
    };
```

And I initialize my adapter:

```
    adapter = new FilesAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.file,
            fileData);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Later, after some network stuff, I update the adapter's data. This is where I think I might be going wrong.

```
PutioFileLayout[] files = blah blah, stuff. I've confirmed in debug that this array is correct and has the correct number of values.
adapter.data = files;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The result of all that is the ListView showing the very first item in the array, and nothing else.

If I add a second Loading... row or similar when I initialize it, it shows the first two. Etcetera.

Am I missing something? What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update `ArrayAdapter` use `ArrayList` instead of `Array`. Because if you are using `Array`, `ArrayAdapter` will use `List` internally which can't be updated.

Rewrite your constructor

```
public FilesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<PutioFileLayout> list) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, list);
    ...
}
```

In `getView()` you get item by invoking `getItem(position)`.

To initialize your adapter use `adapter = new FilesAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.file, new ArrayList<PutioFileLayout>());`

And to fill your adapter use `adapter.add(new PutioFileLayout(...));`

Comment: +1 and addition: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` should be called if data of adapter was changed. This will force a refresh of the displayed data.

Comment: Actually `ArrayAdapter.add()` calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` itself after adding an item so it is not required.

Comment: You're right. Didn't know that, never used `add()` before. Good work.

Comment: So far so good, but when I change the constructor, I get this error on the `PutioFileLayout data[] = null;` line: `Cannot refer to an instance field data while explicitly invoking a constructor`. Or should I be changing that to be an `ArrayList`?  EDIT: Never mind, I'm stupid. Changed the variable name by accident.